# Show Unread Messages on email shortcut?

Tags: motorola-droid-razr

On my old phone* my gmail shortcut would list the number of unread messages I had in my inbox. 
I can't figure out how to do this on my Razr. Is there a good app/widget I can use for this if there is nothing built in?

*An HTC Incredible.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you had the [Google Unread Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.alexanderblom.gmailunreadcount) app on your old phone?

Comment: Nope. And I just tried it on the new phone, but it crashes when I try and put it on the "desktop".

Comment: There is another app from the same author; a paid sequal, $0.99. You might want to see if that later version works where the other failed, if you're willing to spend a dollar.